# Basic HTTP Authentication (how to login as client using php)

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I need some help with Basic HTTP Authentication. Can I login using php from the client side? What kind of tags do I put the following code?

```
GET /rest/v1/locales/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.2dehands.com
Authorization: Basic eHl6OjEyMw==
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you find the answer to your question helpful, accept it by selecting green check mark on the left side of that answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to send HTTP request to the URL and in PHP we have `cURL` to do that, also you have mentioned Basic Authentication.

Also note that `CURLOPT_USERPWD` basically sends the base64 of the `user:password` string with http header like below:

```
Authorization: Basic eHl6OjEyMw==
```

Here is an example of the same,

```
$url = 'http://api.2dehands.com/rest/v1/locales/';

$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    // add more options if you wish
$response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

`$response` will contain your response from `$url`

Comment: Thanks gonna give it a try.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)